# Removing the "broken shield" icon

Tags: hero-academy

I got hit by a mega-rocket and have a broken shield icon over my head. I haven't noticed this on my previously revived units—when does it appear and what does it do? Can I repair my defenses, or am I permanently impaired?

[image: Broken shield]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Annihilator gives every unit (and crystal) it directly hits a temporary armour penalty of -50%, which is indicated by the broken shield icon.  Note that the units that suffer the area of effect damage from the Annihilator do not get the armour penalty.

The penalty is temporary, as it only remains until the unit takes physical damage and suffers the penalty.  After that, the unit's armour rating returns to normal and the icon goes away.

The Team Fortress 2 Jarate item uses the same icon, though it also adds a haze effect around the unit.  In the case of Jarate, the icon indicates that the unit has a temporary armour penalty of -175% AND a temporary magical defense penalty of -175%.  The penalty goes away after any attack.